# How to export pdf to xml in indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am working with my friend, who is creating invoice template in InDesign. I would like to get this document in the XML form, so that I can add lines to it (using Java), and convert it back to PDF.

However, whenever we are trying to export file to XML, we get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root></Root>
```

Any idea why is this happening? The file is already completed.

Answer (score 1):

Why you show reveals that the document has none tagged contents. The InDesign XML structure doesn't represent the document as it in real time. If you ever tag some content within the layout then the structure is appended and once exported you will find this content within the XML. 
Note that you can add content to the structure and this content may not be placed within the layout.
So once again no dynamic relation ship between the InDesign XML structure and the inner contents of the documents. 
You may be more interested in IDML which consists in a bunch of XML files that faithfully represent the true content of the file.